# pixi.jsを使ったゲームがMONACAデバッガーアプリでは動くがAndoroidのデバッグビルドでは動かない

Tags: android, monaca, pixi.js

pixi.jsを使ったゲームを作っています。

MONACAデバッガーアプリでは問題なく動くんですが、
AndoroidのデバッグビルドはMONACAというスプラッシュ画面が表示されたあと、真っ白で何も表示されません。

端末はHTC21L　android4.1   openGLではなくcanvasでレンダリングさせています。
どのような問題が起こっているんでしょう？？？

Comment: cordovaは端末に搭載されたブラウザを利用して動作する（最新バージョンでは独自ブラウザの導入できるようですが）ため、html,css,javascriptの挙動が若干異なることがあります。リモートデバッグを利用して実機のエラーを抽出してみることをおすすめします。http://debug.build.phonegap.com（重いためローカル環境にweinreを導入するほうが快適かもしれません）

Comment: Crosswalk版 (ハイパフォーマンス版) でビルドしてみることをおすすめします。
http://blog.asial.co.jp/1296

Comment: Crosswalk版 (ハイパフォーマンス版) でビルドすると起動した瞬間に、問題が発生と表示されて落ちてしまうのです。
かなしい。

Comment: ゲームアプリでは、どのプラグインを使用していますか？

Comment: おお！　プラグインが間違っていました。
Media APIが必要なコードを書いているのに、Mediaプラグインを追加していませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

明確な回答をするのが難しいので、「答え」ではないのですが、下記のページにある「Chrome のリモートデバッグ機能と Monaca デバッガー 」が有効だと思います。起動時に何かしら、JavaScriptのエラーが出力されていると思いますので、端末をUSBを繋いでデバッグしてみてください。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/debugger/debug/

デバッガーでのデバッグが使えない場合には上記のデバッグ方法はかなり有効です。ビルドした後は自分はいつもこの方法でデバッグしています。